# boost::spirit::qi keywords and identifiers

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I've seen a few posts related to the nuances of keyword/identifier use in qi grammars, but I can't quite make sense of how the approach demonstrated in the boost examples is supposed to work...

Keywords declaration:

```
qi::symbols<char> keywords;
```

Example keyword set:

```
keywords.add
        ("foo")
        ("bar")
        ;
```

Identifier rule declaration:

```
qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type> identifier;
```

Here's how the identifier rule is defined in the qi calc and compiler examples:

```
identifier = !keywords >> qi::raw[ qi::lexeme[ ( qi::alpha | '_' ) >> *( qi::alnum | '_' ) ] ];
```

Perhaps I'm reading the qi syntax wrong, but it seems to me that this would not accept any literal that matches or *starts with* a keyword. Rejecting a full keyword match is the desired behavior. But, I want to accept "food" as an identifier, even though it begins with the keyword "foo". This seems like a pretty standard use case, but having trouble finding documentation that really nails this down.

Can anyone offer an identifier rule that only rejects exact matches to keywords?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually this question deserves some votes. It should be much more oft realized, and probably be addressed in the Spirit Tutorials, as it's often overlooked (obviously **[the compiler samples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/compiler_tutorial/)** are ok)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this question deserves some votes. It should be much more oft realized, and probably be addressed in the Spirit Tutorials, as it's often overlooked (obviously **[the compiler samples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/compiler_tutorial/)** are ok)

---

> Perhaps I'm reading the qi syntax wrong, but it seems to me that this would not accept any literal that matches or starts with a keyword.

That's correct. In case you spotted in one of my own answers (quite a good chance) I tend to do this as a quick-and-dirty way to fixup grammars that didn't have proper keyword guards there in the first place.

But yeah, requiring distinct keywords/identifiers requires some more work. I might find a link to an answer where it's done correctly (it's not hard, it's just tedious).

Meanwhile, have a look at the very relevant

- **[Qi `distinct` Parser Directive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/spirit/repository/doc/html/spirit_repository/qi_components/directives/distinct.html)** from the Spirit Repository

If you're building a really robust general-purpose language grammar, this is about the point where you should consider using a Spirit Lexer. Then again, in my humble opinion, Spirit aims at rapid development and small, one-off grammars that are succinctly embedded using Spirit's expression template eDSL. In a lot of aspects, that is much the antipode of when this matters, I reckon.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. This clears it up. I was aware of the distinct directive, but thought I might be missing something with that quick-fix. Thanks!