# Defining a symbol which may be part of a literal function in boost spirit

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-phoenix

I am trying to read a mathematical function which depends on the symbol `t` with boost::spirit.

In the example below, I'm trying evaluate  the function `"tan(t)"` in `t=1.2`. 
Instead of having

```
Exit: 1, value = 2.5721
```

I get

```
Exit: 1, value = 1.2
```

I understand that when I try to read the function `"tan(t)"`, instead of computing the tangent of `t`, the value of `t` is assigned to the first letter in the word `tan`. Is it possible to circumvent this behavior, without changing the symbol `t`? Moreover, shouldn't the parse fail?

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_symbols.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/stl/cmath.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii=boost::spirit::ascii;
using boost::spirit::ascii::space;
using boost::spirit::qi::symbols;


template< typename Iterator >
struct Grammar : public qi::grammar<  Iterator, double(), ascii::space_type >
{

    Grammar() : Grammar::base_type(expression)
    {
        using qi::double_;
        using qi::_val;
        using qi::_1;

        expression = double_                   [_val = _1]
                    | symbol                   [_val = _1]
                    | function                 [_val = _1]
                    | group                    [_val = _1];

        function =  qi::lit("tan")  >> group   [_val = boost::phoenix::tan(_1)];
        group = '(' >> expression   [_val = _1] >> ')' ;
  }

    qi::rule<Iterator, double(), ascii::space_type> expression, function, group;
    qi::symbols<char, double > symbol;
};


int main()
{
    typedef std::string::iterator iterator;
    Grammar<iterator> grammar;
    std::string function = "tan(t)"; //it would work if function = "tan(x)"
    grammar.symbol.add("t",1.2);     // and add("x",1.2)
    double value;
    bool r = qi::phrase_parse(function.begin(), function.end(), grammar, space, value);
    std::cout << "Exit: " << r << ", value = " << value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need any of the `[_val=_1]` semantic actions. [Boost Spirit: “Semantic actions are evil”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reorder you rules. Your symbol (`t`) is eating the first letter of `tan`. So, you're not actually parsing all input at all!

If you enable debugging you'd see this output:

```
<expression>
<try>tan(t)</try>
<success>an(t)</success>
<attributes>[1.2]</attributes>
</expression>
Exit: 1, value = 1.2
```

The "Royal Way" to fix this is using the Qi Distinct Keyword directive from the Spirit Repository: [boost::spirit::qi keywords and identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463338/boostspiritqi-keywords-and-identifiers/27464697#27464697)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b37a75192d4fc516)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_symbols.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_distinct.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/stl/cmath.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii=boost::spirit::ascii;
using boost::spirit::ascii::space;
using boost::spirit::qi::symbols;


template< typename Iterator >
struct Grammar : public qi::grammar<  Iterator, double(), ascii::space_type >
{

    Grammar() : Grammar::base_type(expression)
    {
        using qi::double_;
        using qi::_val;
        using qi::_1;
        using boost::spirit::repository::qi::distinct;

        expression = double_
                   | distinct(qi::char_("a-zAZ09_")) [ symbol ]
                   | function
                   | group;

        function =  "tan"  >> group [_val = boost::phoenix::tan(_1)];
        group = '(' >> expression >> ')' ;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((expression)(function)(group));
  }

    qi::rule<Iterator, double(), ascii::space_type> expression, function, group;
    qi::symbols<char, double > symbol;
};


int main()
{
    typedef std::string::iterator iterator;
    Grammar<iterator> grammar;
    std::string function = "tan(t)";
    grammar.symbol.add("t",1.2);
    double value;
    bool r = qi::phrase_parse(function.begin(), function.end(), grammar, space, value);
    std::cout << "Exit: " << r << ", value = " << value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output with debug information is:

```
<expression>
  <try>tan(t)</try>
  <function>
    <try>tan(t)</try>
    <group>
      <try>(t)</try>
      <expression>
        <try>t)</try>
        <success>)</success>
        <attributes>[1.2]</attributes>
      </expression>
      <success></success>
      <attributes>[1.2]</attributes>
    </group>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[2.57215]</attributes>
  </function>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[2.57215]</attributes>
</expression>
Exit: 1, value = 2.57215
```