# How to allow ok spaces and ban bad ones with boost spirit

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit-x3

Motivating examples
good:

```
 SELECT   a, b,  c    d,e FROM t1
```

bad:

```
SE L ECT a, b, c    d,e FR OM t1

SELECTa, b, c    d,eFROMt1
```

So as you can see problem here is that some spaces are ok(between SELECT and a,b,c for example) and some are bad(SE L ECT) and some are neccessary(after/before keyword).

So my question is what idioms to use here since if I use `space` skipper with `phrase_parse` it will allow bad spaces and if I want to allow good spaces without a skipper parsers become littered with `*char_(' ')`

Comment: Sounds to me, what you're looking for is a regex; or better yet, a check of the result of your SQL query?

Comment: this is mostly about parsing with boost spirit, this is just a toy example, real problems of this kind can not be nicely solved with regex

Comment: If you provide a logical definition what "good" or "bad" space means, as a technical specification, then it can be translated directly into code. But vague, nebulous concepts like "good" or "bad" is something that's not directly translatable into software.

Answer (score 3):

You need to mark your keywords as `qi::lexeme[]`.

Besides, you probably want something like `boost::spirit::repository::qi::distinct` to avoid parsing `SELECT2` as `SELECT` followed by 2.\

See e.g.

- [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)
- [boost::spirit::qi keywords and identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463338/boostspiritqi-keywords-and-identifiers/27464697#27464697)

Comment: nice answer, and just to give some more info to it I think in my example this from your other answer is true: "If you're building a really robust general-purpose language grammar, this is about the point where you should consider using a Spirit Lexer. "   Rage in comment  reply if I am wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is, well, parsing.

It's not about accepting/rejecting "good" or "bad" spaces. It is about trying to recognize what's entered, and rejecting it if you can't.

In this case, let's start with a (thoroughly simplified) grammar for the statement in question:

```
select_statement ::= 'select' field_list 'from' table
```

So, you read in the first token. If it's `SE` or `SELECTa`, you reject the statement as invalid, because neither of those fits your grammar. Almost any decent parser generator (including, but certainly not limited to, Spirit) makes this fairly trivial--you specify what *is* acceptable, and what to do if the input is *not* acceptable, and it deals with invoking that for input that doesn't fit the specified grammar.

As for how you do the tokenization to start with, it's *typically* pretty simple, and usually *can* be based on regular expressions (e.g., *many* languages have been implemented using `lex` and derivatives like Flex, which use regexen to specify tokenization).

For something like this, you directly specify the keywords for your language, so you'd have something that says when it matches 'select', it should return that as a token. Then you have something more general for an identifier that typically runs something like `[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*' ("an identifier starts with an underscore or letter, followed by an arbitrary number of underscores, letters, or digits"). In the cases above, this would be entirely sufficient to find and return the "SE" and "SELECTa" as the first tokens in the "bad" examples.

Your parser would then detect that the first thing it received was an identifier instead of a key word, at which point it would (presumably) be rejected.

Comment: One of the few cases where "you can use a regular expression to solve your problem" does not leave you with two problems, because nobody sane uses an insane pattern for "identifier".

Comment: The spirit translation of this approach would be to use a Spirit Lex tokenizer. I won't recommend it as it complicates use of Spirit to the point I don't think it hits a sweet spot any more